# Take the first unique value of a big set in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a big big set, but I just want to take the first unique value of each set of an specific column (c.id).

I have so far this, and it works.. But I need to get 1 record per different c.ID, because now I get several c.ID, I just want to ignore and just have a UNIQUE or FIRST value of c.ID

```
Select
    s.room,
    s.EXPRESSION,
    c.ID,
    c.COURSE_NAME,
    s.ROOM,
    t.FIRST_NAME,
    t.LAST_NAME,
    std.GRADE_LEVEL,
    CASE s.SCHOOLID
        WHEN 300 THEN 'MiddleSchool'
        WHEN 400 THEN 'UpperSchool'
        WHEN 200 THEN 'LowerSchool'
        WHEN 100 THEN 'ECC'
        ELSE 'miau'
        END AS "School"
  from   sections s
  INNER JOIN COURSES c ON s.COURSE_NUMBER=c.COURSE_NUMBER
  INNER JOIN TEACHERS t ON s.TEACHER=t.ID
  INNER JOIN CC co ON s.ID=co.SECTIONID
  INNER JOIN STUDENTS std ON std.ID = co.STUDENTID
  WHERE s.TERMID IN (2800, 2801, 2803, 2804)
  AND t.LAST_NAME='Dilworth'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the sample data. It will easy to help you

Comment: And the expected output

Answer (score 0):

What do you call "first"? Rows in a table in relational database are like balls in a basket; there's no "order", unless you apply one.

The way you put it, you don't really care which one it is, so - take any of them. A simple way to do that is to use one of aggregation functions (such as `MIN`) and put everything else into `GROUP BY` clause, such as

```
select
  s.room,
  s.expression,
  min(c.ID) max_id
from ...
where ...
group by s.room, 
         s.expression;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    Select s.room, s.EXPRESSION, c.ID, c.COURSE_NAME, /* s.ROOM why twice? */,
        t.FIRST_NAME, t.LAST_NAME, std.GRADE_LEVEL,
        CASE s.SCHOOLID
            WHEN 300 THEN 'MiddleSchool'
            WHEN 400 THEN 'UpperSchool'
            WHEN 200 THEN 'LowerSchool'
            WHEN 100 THEN 'ECC'
            ELSE 'miau'
        END AS "School",
        row_number() over (partition by c.ID order by ??) as rn /* which is first? */
    from sections s
        INNER JOIN COURSES c ON s.COURSE_NUMBER = c.COURSE_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN TEACHERS t ON s.TEACHER = t.ID
        INNER JOIN CC co ON s.ID = co.SECTIONID
        INNER JOIN STUDENTS std ON std.ID = co.STUDENTID
    WHERE s.TERMID IN (2800, 2801, 2803, 2804) AND t.LAST_NAME = 'Dilworth'
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```